# How is gallery.css file generated?

Tags: magento2.2, product-page, less-css

I'm adding some custom less to product page on Magento 2.2.2

I've notice that now, many of my customization are included in `gallery.css` file and I'm not able to change them anymore in my custom less because it's loaded before gallery.css

Which should be the trick to override it without using `!important`?

Comment: Can you please let me know where are you adding your custom css?

Comment: Please provide me file path

Answer (score 3):

please follow below step to compile **`"gallery.less"`**

1. create **"mage"** folder under your theme
2. copy **"gallery"** folder from **"root/lib/web/mage/gallery/"** and put under **"app/design/frontend/vendor(packagename)/your-theme(custom theme)/web/mage/"**
3. open **"root/dev/tools/grunt/configs/theme.js"** and put below code in it (configure your theme in **"theme.js"**)

   ```
   theme: {
   area: 'frontend',
   name: 'vendor/your-theme',
   locale: 'en_US',
   files: [
       'css/styles-m',
       'css/styles-l',
       'mage/gallery/gallery',
   ],
   dsl: 'less'
   ```

   }
4. clean **root/var/ and pub/static** folder
5. run grunt **exec:theme** (your-theme)
6. run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**
7. run **grunt watch:theme** (your-theme)
8. modify "gallery.less", now it is compile through grunt

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove this file then add below code in `<theme_dir>\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml` file.

```
<head>
   <remove src="mage/gallery/gallery.css" />
</head>
```

**If you want to edit gallery style:**

If you are not locate this file in `<theme_dir>\web\mage\gallery` then copy `gallery.less` file from `<root>\lib\web\mage\gallery` and add in your theme.

**Run command:**

- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

**en_US** folder is generate from themes when you run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`.

Comment: Yes, this is clear. But why inside gallery.css in pub/static is included my custom css for product page?

Comment: You need to default mage folder in your theme folder and then you need to apply your custom css. That's standard process.

Comment: Can you please provide me more information.